# How to center child div in a fixed parent div that has left margin?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent and a child div.

Margin left and right does not work in this situation, what works is if I set parent div to `width: -webkit-fill-available;`, but I am not sure if this is correct way to use for all the internet browsers and fixed positioning?

The code:

```css
.parent {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 275px;
    width: 100%;
}


.child {
    background-color: green;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child ">
        <a class="child-a" href="/url" target="_blank">
        Here is the text.
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey can you provide your html code also

Comment: if your child is a block element, it would take the full width of the parent so what are you trying to center?  Also as your parent has a width of 100% this will be pushed off the screen by your left margin

Comment: Aahad, added HTML code.
Pete, the link / text is inside and width auto works to set auto width around text or the link.

Comment: inspect your child element - it fills the full width of the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust parent properties as below:

```
.parent {
  width: calc(100% - 275px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

We recalculate parent width without the length of margin.
and then just set `text-align:center;`

If it is for a navbar, I would suggest to not use margin fixed like this.

### DEMO Based on your code

```css
.parent {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 275px;
    width: calc(100% - 275px);
    height:20px; /****ADDED for snippet****/
    text-align: center;
}


.child {
    background-color: green;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height:100%; /****ADDED for snippet****/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child ">
        <a class="child-a" href="/url" target="_blank">
        Here is the text.
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin but rely on left/right

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 275px;
  right: 0;
  text-align:center;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child ">
    <a class="child-a" href="/url" target="_blank">
        Here is the text.
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```